# How to create a costum JSON response in Spring Java?

Tags: java, spring

Currently, I am  trying to return a costum created response from my REST API. My goal is to create the following response.

```
{
   "status": "Success",
   "message": "More details here",
   "data": {
      "records": [
         {
            "record": "Lorem ipsum",
            "code": 0,
            "errors": null
         },
         {
            "record": "Lorem ipsum",
            "code": 1,
            "errors": [
               "First error",
               "Second error"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

My API endpoint looks like the following.

```
@PostMapping(value="/my-url", 
   consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
   produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Response check_records(@RequestBody(required=true) Records records) {
   // Do Stuff
}
```

The 'Response' class:

```
public class Response {
   private String status;
   private String message;
   private Map<String, List<RecordResponse>> data;
   
   // Default getter / setter
}
```

The 'RecordResponse' class:

```
public class RecordResponse {
   private String record;
   private Integer code;
   private String[] errors;
```

The response itself is returning anything but JSON. Neither way it is returning an error or returns the object reference in the json:

```
{
   "status": "Success",
   "message": "More details here",
   "data": {com.example.restservice.data@2071af5d}
}
```

Comment: I dont understand "returns anything but json". What does it return?? You can use `@ResponseBody` to make sure you are returning json. The structure will be of the object you are returning.

Comment: @JAsgarov Sure, I've edited my question. I think the problem is, that my response class references or contains other classes

Comment: `private List<String, List<RecordResponse>> data;` List gets 1 generic argument, how did you end up with 2? Probably map huh?

Comment: @Antoniossss Little typo^^ Lemme fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generics to have a decent typecontroll for your response wrapper

```
public class Response<T> {
   private String status;
   private String message;
   private T data;

   //all args contructor
}
```

and

```
public class Records{
  List<RecordResponse> records;
}

public class RecordResponse {
   private String record;
   private Integer code;
   private String[] errors;



public Response<Records> check_records(@RequestBody(required=true) Records records) {
    RecordResponse recordResponses=//build responses 
    Records records=//build records
    return new Response<Records>(status,message,records);
}
```

This should produce response close if not exact as you have requested

Comment: Your suggestions leads to an `HTTP/1.1 500` error. I had the same error before, probably because the endpoint can't serialize any JSON from the given object. I've overwrote the toString() methods last time, but I don't know if this works now & it created an incorrect JSON string at the end. Is there any way to get the same result with a map as data?

Comment: 500 is internal error - just check the stacktrace.

Comment: My fault - It creates the wanted output. Nevertheless my JSON is still incorrect: `Unexpected end of string`. Any idea how to fix that? The record string contains multiple `"`. the API put "\" before in order to escape them but the error still appears